# Pre-filter readable data based on user permissions with Flask-Admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm using flask-admin to create a simple backend for my database.
I'd like to only show parts of a table, based on a pre-filtering, based on the permissions the user has. 
For example, if the table has all the sales of a company, i would like to only show the sales of salesperson 'foo' when 'foo' accesses the backend

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself? Have you encountered any problems in the attempt? What are those specific problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution is overriding the method 'get_query'

It should return a SQLAlchemy query object.

```
def get_query(self):
    role = current_user.role
    if role == 'contributor':
        return # filtered query
    elif role == 'admin':
        return # unfiltered query
```